# Autoboxing with primitive type in type of generic class?

Tags: java

Why `List<int> list1 = new ArrayList<>();` doesn't working, and why `List<int[]> list3 = new ArrayList<>();` and `List<Integer[]> list4 = new ArrayList<>();` is working?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<int> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); // why is doesn't working
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<int[]> list3 = new ArrayList<>(); // why working
        List<Integer[]> list4 = new ArrayList<>(); // why working
    }
}
```

Comment: `int` is a primitive type, `int[]` is a reference type (`new int[0] instanceof Object` is true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java Generics, you never make a primitive type as a reference,  like :

```
List<int> List<double> ArrayList<long>
```

because those aren't objects !!
int the java Generics, we code the generic classes with objects !!

Answer (score 2):

In java, you have primitive types and you have reference types.
`int` is a primitive type and `Integer` is a reference type.

In java generics you have *type parameters*. In other words, a type parameter is a place holder that can be replaced by the name of a reference type. A type parameter **cannot** be replaced with a primitive type. Hence `List<int>` is not allowed.

`List<Integer>` is allowed since `Integer` is a reference type.

In java, an array is also a reference type, even if it is an array of primitive types. Hence `int[]` is a reference type and therefore `List<int[]>` is allowed.

Comment: Primitive types are types, they don't exist outside the type system. What you call "types" should be called "reference types".

Comment: @JoachimSauer look again, please.

Comment: ```List<int> list1 = new ArrayList<>();``` I understand why it is not working if autoboxing doesnt't existed. But why ```int``` doesn't get converted into ```Integer```?

Comment: @Denis_newbie autoboxing does not apply to type parameters. By the way, the java API documentation uses the term **Type Parameters** Refer to, for example, the _javadoc_ for class [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)